# Upgrading Python 3.6 to 3.7 in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: python3

Since Python 3.7 is already launched, I wanted to ask when will Ubuntu 18.04 will get an update to upgrade the Python3'sversion?

Comment: It won't.  As everything depends on Python to work, upgrading a Python version on a stable release could make everything not function, which is why the Python version is version-locked in the repositories.  You would need to find  a third party PPA with a co-installable Python 3.7 in order to get newer Python on that version of Ubuntu.  See this relevant/related post: https://askubuntu.com/questions/151283/why-dont-the-ubuntu-repositories-have-the-latest-versions-of-software

Comment: I really wish this Question was not locked, the supposedly duplicate linked question is much more generic than this one. I would like to post an answer to the question `Upgrading Python 3.6 to 3.7 in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No

Ubuntu uses a [*snapshot* method](https://askubuntu.com/questions/151283/why-dont-the-ubuntu-repositories-have-the-latest-versions-of-software) of populating the software repositories. After release, the only changes are for security and major bugfixes. In addition, a great deal of the system depends upon a specific version of python - upgrading python may break those services (like apt).

Historically, Ubuntu has never upgraded to the next major version of Python or Python3 during a release. All upgrades occur during pre-release testing.

Comment: So it's completely version locked?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by 'version locked'. If you install a somewhere-else package of 3.7, *replacing* 3.6, you are likely to break your system quite badly. If you install a somewhere-else package of 3.7 *alongside* 3.6, you must have the skills to do so properly...or you will break your system quite badly.

Comment: @user535733 yes, you are right. I should read your comment earlier.

Answer (score 2):

If you need the newest python version, I recommend to use python environments like **[Anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/)** or others. The Pros are that you can install several environments with different python and package versisons with a tool called conda. 
So you don't get problems with your system python's.